# Resizing bulk images in an folder using opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I tried the following code to resize images in a directory but it ended up with this error
error: (-215) ssize.width > 0 && ssize.height > 0 in function cv::resize

```
import cv2
import numpy as numpy

for idx in range(85):
    im = cv2.imread('IDRiD_'+str(idx)+'.jpg')
    im1 = cv2.resize(im, (0,0), fx=0.2, fy=0.2)
    cv2.imwrite('resized_image\IDRID'+str(idx)+'.jpg', im1)
    print('IDRiD_'+str(idx)+'.jpg is resized')
```

Comment: The path you're passing to `imread` is wrong, so it returns an empty image.

Comment: the Problem was with the path and the range... Thank You it worked